# Ошибка при использовании pandas concat

Tags: python, pandas

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from lxml import etree
from numpy import FLOATING_POINT_SUPPORT
import requests
from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelWriter
import string
import pandas as pd


def get_html(url):
    result = requests.get(url).text
    f = fromstring(result)
    return f

def get_data(html):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Раздел 1', 'Описание раздела 1', 'симвовольный код 1', 'title 1', 'description 1', 'keywords 1', 
                            'Раздел 2', 'Описание раздела 2', 'симвовольный код 2', 'title 2', 'description 2', 'keywords 2', 
                            'Наименование элемента', 'Хлебные крошки', 'url', 'title 1', 'Детальное описание', 'Видео', 'Старая цена', 'Новая цена'))

    for product in html.cssselect('.product-container'):
        a = product.cssselect('a')[0]
        href = a.get('href')
        
        ar = requests.get(href).text
        af = fromstring(ar)



        bread1 = af.cssselect('.breadcrumb a')[2].text_content()
        bread2 = af.cssselect('.breadcrumb a')[3].text_content()
        breadcrumb = af.cssselect('.breadcrumb')[0].text_content()

        title = af.cssselect('#product-name-wrap h1')[0].text_content()
        price = af.cssselect('#our_price_display')[0].text_content()
        

        opis = af.cssselect('.product-info-partblock')[0]
        description = etree.tostring(opis, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')
        
        try:
            video = af.cssselect('.product-info-partblock')[3]
            vedios = etree.tostring(video, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')
        except IndexError:
            vedios = ''
        
        test = ''
        
        klevielodki_list = [('Раздел 1', test), 
                            ('Описание раздела 1', test),
                            ('симвовольный код 1', test),
                            ('title 1', test),
                            ('description 1', test),
                            ('Раздел 2', test),
                            ('Описание раздела 2', test),
                            ('симвовольный код 2', test),
                            ('title 2', test),
                            ('description 2', test),
                            ('keywords 2', test),
                            ('Наименование элемента', title),
                            ('Хлебные крошки', breadcrumb),
                            ('url', href),
                            ('title 1', title),
                            ('Детальное описание', description),
                            ('Видео', vedios),
                            ('Старая цена', price),
                            ('Новая цена', test)]
        
        for xarik in af.cssselect('.product-info-content tr'):
            alfa = xarik.cssselect('td')[0].text_content()
            beta = xarik.cssselect('td')[1].text_content()
            klevielodki_list.append((alfa, beta))
        
        img = 0
        for images in af.cssselect('#thumbs_list_frame li'):
            ia = images.cssselect('a')[0]
            ih = ia.get('href')
            lir = requests.get(ih)
            out = open('img/%s' % ih.split('/')[-2]+'.jpg', 'wb')
            out.write(lir.content)
            out.close()
            img += 1
            klevielodki_list.append(('img%s' % img, ih.split('/')[-2]+'.jpg'))
        
        df = pd.concat(klevielodki_list, ignore_index=True)
        print(df)
    
    writer = ExcelWriter('клевыелодки.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='1', header=True, index=False)
    writer.save()   




                
def main():
    html = get_html('https://klevielodki.ru/12-modeli-lodok/?id_category=12&n=245')
    get_data(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

парсю сайт, у меня выходит ошибка, помогите пожалуйста

> Exception has occurred: TypeError cannot concatenate object of type
> '<class 'tuple'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid   File
> "/home/artddss/python/em/bicom/klevielodki.py", line 86, in get_data
> df = pd.concat(klevielodki_list, ignore_index=True)   File "/home/artddss/python/em/bicom/klevielodki.py", line 99, in main
> get_data(html)   File "/home/artddss/python/em/bicom/klevielodki.py", line 103, in 
> main() TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'tuple'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: `pd.concat` умеет объединять только объекты `Pandas` - датафреймы, либо серии. А вы пытаетесь состыковать список кортежей. Если вы хотите из этого списка кортежей сделать датафрейм, попробуйте `pd.DataFrame` вместо `pd.concat`.

Comment: я раньше использовал df.append, но он теперь поменяли на contact, чет вообще разобраться не могу. dataframe не помогает замена с contact

Comment: Ну у вас там что-то непонятное получается в списке в итоге. Сначала разберитесь, что у вас в этом списке получилось, какого оно формата вообще. У вас там произвольно число элементов что ли вообще получается в строке?

Comment: @CrazyElf выходит все в одну строку

Comment: А, ну тогда наверное нужно делать `df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(klevielodki_list)])`

Comment: ошибка
Exception has occurred: InvalidIndexError
Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Ну попробуйте `, ignore_index=True` обратно туда добавить. Сложно что-то советовать, не видя данные.

Comment: все не то, идет какое то гадание

Comment: @CrazyElf раньше делал так df = df.append(dict(klevielodki_list), ignore_index=True), теперь append убрали вместо него contact, чет разобраться не могу